# I am getting "message": "Unauthenticated." after generating the token

Tags: laravel, oauth, postman, token, laravel-passport

I am using Laravel 8 and after generating token I got "message": "Unauthenticated.".

```
Accept is application/json

Authorization is Bearer eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOiJSUzI1NiJ9.eyJhdWQiOiI4IiwianRpIjoiNWEwZTMxMjU3YmU4OWM1YWQyMjcxZDZiMjBmNGRmZWEzMDk2ZTU2YWUyNmMxNjljZDQ5NmNhZjVhNjdlNmQ2OTFiMTAzMTdmYTAzNmJjOGYiLCJpYXQiOjE2MjQ4MDkwMTIsIm5iZiI6MTYyNDgwOTAxMiwiZXhwIjoxNjI3NDA2NDU3LCJzdWIiOiIiLCJzY29wZXMiOltdfQ.X5IQ3sb2TSYdzp9oEyn-CODL79DDE9ezUsv5jCDNsJSeJsbe3gTuzEeJ6ENIc8ZDGwOZ0-JCqIZuTOK39i7IYZ2Q4S4ctO0vp6DEw7HaDVa0bWpFO7bVC9d05rbBsZpzmidMixerwOgT1GAILBVTI_qKQyjdaKHV1m9qihU5AMQ2XCceq0m9RL24T2Pg4NV8xsOxkv3pl4TDCBfZ8MwdKBZ5Z0WTJAh6YFrKGSLhZOA0u9aSl6iuaJGAR_LblTdugjsmwkfijMzRR4wucaa67wbL6HF0eUpvPQ0rdoc1VgR4D_Y8nWfLfCOi1PNsitnc8-Qbr7t8ijLnKe0tDmJVvNxq49TNKnFv_y-EcumIOW1pzzQKvX1zWMS2yrsqlbhftN5dJWGbwA01qZpjJITyGW1C-VOEVG_Wpcjxlk7rd4vIghq4IiTzlUu3Mz4s7aLAtdyaNT0Mkv1aurG4L0hOmvrZkJaiiNtrGNcWBkU9yc9ISFUaFagszOnDo52YPnzu7CCDNk0ekUIWQwsJlA7Tcbib69JuL_XpD9fMcz0QD1BhHkCEdPna7rhtcT-xOto0QOL5YluHW7svwcSuYc5JcoLXwdLLFNlkyxFcbYIYjyOjc8ytMvYYZsar36waLL7boOiu5DyvjHDqnStBvJIHXAWSs-Y6DfGAVvTxOoqwEa0
```

In the form-data, I have

```
grant_type is client_credentials

client_id is 8

client_secret is mOu1oBuLHyExwTnRY9Noq9MvQdnbHkNKmPkdVyrz
```

In my AuthServiceProvider

```
public function boot()
    {
        $this->registerPolicies();
        Passport::routes();

        $startTime = date("Y-m-d H:i:s");
        $endTime = date("Y-m-s H:i:s", strtotime('+7 day +1 hour +30 minutes +45 seconds', strtotime($startTime)));
        $expTime = \DateTime::createFromFormat("Y-m-s H:i:s", $endTime);
        Passport::tokensExpireIn($expTime);
        //
    }
```

In my config/auth.php

```
'guards' => [
        'web' => [
            'driver' => 'session',
            'provider' => 'users',
        ],

        'api' => [
            'driver' => 'passport',
            'provider' => 'users',
            'hash' => false,
        ],
    ],
```

In my api.php

```
Route::group(['middleware' => 'auth:api'], function(){
    Route::get('country', [CountryController::class, 'country']); 
    Route::get('country/{id}', [CountryController::class, 'countryById']);
    Route::post('country', [CountryController::class, 'countrySave']); 
    Route::put('country/{id}', [CountryController::class, 'countryUpdate']); 
    Route::delete('country/{id}', [CountryController::class, 'countryDelete']); 
});
```

Comment: Do you send the generated token in the header of the request??

Comment: yes i did but its not working

Comment: i have cleared cache and done every solutions i saw online but its still not working

Comment: @TohidDadashnezhad Please kindly assist